# Show $A^{\mathrm{Card}(GL_2(\mathbb{Z/p\mathbb{Z})})+2}=A^2$ for any $A \in \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{Z/p\mathbb{Z}})$

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number. I have shown that $\mathrm{Card}(GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})) = (p^2-1)(p^2-p)$ let's call it $n$.

I want to show that,

> $$\forall A \in \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{Z/p\mathbb{Z}}), \quad A^{n+2} = A^2$$

---

What I've done so far:

Let $A \in \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{Z/p\mathbb{Z}})$.

If $A$ is invertible then as
$\big[GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}),\times\big]$ is a group, we have $A^n = I_2$ therefore $A^{n+2} = A^2$.

Now I want to show that the result holds when $A$ is not invertible. I do not have much ideas for the moment. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's a classic argument that invertible matrices are dense (in Zariski topology), and a polynomial equation valid on a dense set is valid everywhere, but this is probably an overkill and I didn't work out the details.

Comment: @lisyarus Thank you for your answer, but I do not know any of that.

Comment: This is simply a consequence of Lagrange’s theorem

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you. For invertible matrices it is, but can I still use this theorem for when $A$ is not invertible?

Comment: Oh, I missed that $A$ was not necessarily invertible. I’ll have to think about it

Comment: @lisyarus It seems to me that this argument would lead to the false conclusion that $A^{n+1}=A$ for all $2\times 2$ matrices $A$, which fails for instance when $A$ is non-zero but nilpotent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prove the result for the case where $A$ is not invertible, it suffices to note that every non-invertible $A \in \mathcal M_2(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)$ can be expressed in the form
$$
A = uv^T
$$
for some column-vectors $u,v \in (\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^2$, from which it follows that for all integers $k \geq 1$, we have
$$
A^k = (uv^T)^k = u(v^Tu)^{k-1} v^T = (v^Tu)^{k-1} A.
$$
Now, if $v^Tu \neq 0$, then verify that $(v^T u)^n = 1$ (where $n = \mathrm{Card}(GL_2(\mathbb{Z/p\mathbb{Z})})$), so that the result follows. One way to see this is to note that $v^Tu$ has the same order as $(v^Tu)I_2$. If $v^Tu = 0$, verify that $A^{n+2} = A^2 = 0$. Conclude that the result holds for all non-invertible $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It took me some time, but everything is crystal clear now.